# Setting up geoserver-manager in new ecplise project

Tags: eclipse, maven

Been hitting this with the blunt end of my face for the better part of a week--I have reached critical frustration levels.

I've made a new maven project within eclipse and have the following pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>GeoSolutions</id>
            <url>http://maven.geo-solutions.it/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <!-- The Basics -->
    <groupId>ARU</groupId>
    <artifactId>ARU</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.geosolutions</groupId>
            <artifactId>geoserver-manager</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 

    <!-- Project Information -->
    <name>Automatic Raster Update</name>
    <description>Application that automates the update of your raster imagery</description>

    <!-- Build Settings -->
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.4</source>
                <target>1.4</target>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

when I run the pom.xml as a maven build i get the following output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Automatic Raster Update 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ ARU ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\BABS_WMS\v_1.1\js_Dev\ARU\ARU-master\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ ARU ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\BABS_WMS\v_1.1\js_Dev\ARU\ARU-master\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ ARU ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\BABS_WMS\v_1.1\js_Dev\ARU\ARU-master\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.499 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-01-19T13:36:30-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/219M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project ARU: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

The Maven dependencies seems to load, but I get the following with inspecting the build path libs.

[image: For the love of god please something work!]

Where do I go and what do I do?

***UPDATE***
This is the error I get when I try and run my test code
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hey @iant, right now I'm just trying to use geoserver-manager to do some of the REST calls on a geoserver. The project overall will use new imagery and rebuild pyramids to be uploaded to a geoserver

Comment: Try changing the source and target tags to 1. 7 or 1.8

Comment: @iant still giving me that no compiler error on both 1.7 and 1.8

Comment: Do you have a jdk installed?

Comment: @iant, yes JDK 1.7 is default, I have 1.8 also; environment vars pointed to the appropriate bin directories